# Is there a way to get the name of the current file being opened?

Tags: init-file, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to conditionally load configuration in my `init.el`. How can I get the filename (preferable the extension) of the current file being opened?

For example, if I run `emacs foo.rs`, I'd like to know it's a `.rs` file and do some extra stuff in my config.

Comment: What if you do just `emacs` and then inside emacs you open the file: `C-x C-f foo.rs`? Shouldn't the "extra stuff" be done in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several variables contain the [command line arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Command_002dLine-Arguments.html) (“arguments” includes both options and file names), in particular [`command-line-args-left`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Command_002dLine-Arguments.html#index-command_002dline_002dargs_002dleft) which contains the arguments that haven't been processed yet at each point during [startup](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html).

However, it's unusual to access the command line arguments in a user's init file. If there are things you load based on which files are opened initially, they won't work if you open another file within Emacs or via emacsclient.

If you want to run some code when opening a file of a particular type, add it to the [mode hook](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hooks.html) for the corresponding [major mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Major-Modes.html). For example, to run `(my-extra-rust-stuff)` when opening a Rust file:

```
(add-hook 'rust-mode-hook 'my-extra-rust-stuff)
```

To find out the name of the hook variable, check the name of the major mode: open a file of that type and run `C-h v major-mode RET` (value of the variable `major-mode`). Add the suffix `-hook` to the name of the major mode, for example `rust-mode` → `rust-mode-hook`.

If you want to do some one-time initialization that's relevant for all files of a given type, the way to do it is run some additional code after loading the package that provides support for that file type. To see the package name, open a file of that type and run `C-h m` (`describe-mode`). Look for a line like “Rust mode defined in ‘rust-mode.el’:”: `rust-mode` is the name of the package. (Note that it's a bit of a coincidence that this is exactly the same as the major mode name. Not all packages follow this convention.) In your init file, to run `(my-extra-rust-init)` when Rust support is loaded, write

```
(eval-after-load "rust-mode" '(my-extra-rust-init))
```

or

```
(with-eval-after-load "rust-mode"
  (my-extra-rust-init))
```

Comment: Thanks, `with-eval-after-load` is exactly what I was looking for. Doesn't speed up load time the way I hoped it would. :)

Comment: @marcantonio To speed up the load time, make sure you don't `require` or `load` things from your init file. Let things be autoloaded. But also, just start Emacs at the beginning of a session and use `emacsclient` to open files, this way load time is not an issue and working with multiple files is easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you start Emacs specifying a file to visit as a command-line argument, as you describe, and that's pretty much all you do wrt the command line, and your init file doesn't visit any other files or buffers, then this sexp will give you the name of the visited file, which will be the one you specified on the command line:

```lisp
(buffer-file-name)
```